# Eclipse static import content assist doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, m2eclipse

I would like to configure my Eclipse to suggest me static methods of a LazyModel java type when I type them. And to add an appropriate static import of course.

I have enabled using static imports in general Content Assist settings

[image: Eclipse Content Assist settings]

And I have added the LazyModel type to Content Assist Favorites.

[image: Eclipse Favorites settings]

But the Eclipse doesn't suggest me the LazyModel's static methods.
Note that:

- for java.util.stream.Collectors it works perfectly
- the LazyModel type is from maven dependency
- I have tryied to delete all Eclipse's indexes

Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what I was looking for, but if I add all LazyModel static methods as **members** instead of the whole LazyModel **type** to the Favorites, then it works.